# Atom editor basic text selection

Tags: selection, atom-editor

Basic question regarding Atom Editor: Is their anyway to select text by just dragging a left click over text? (Without using shift?) I don't know if this is just a bug I am experiencing, but for some reason I am unable to drag to select text.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert at Atom but this seems to be a bug you're experiencing. It should be possible to select text by dragging. 
I've used versions 0.199.0 up to the current 1.0.0 and it always worked without shift.
Maybe try reinstalling it.

Comment: It is a bug. Here is the github issue: https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/6306